# What is that suspentive の particle?

Tags: grammar, particle-の

I have come several times across the の particle just before a comma （、）but I could not figure out why の was use and for what purpose.

Here are some examples I have run across:

> ex1: [今回はそのようなリスクを少しでも減らすため**の**、チェックリストを呈してみることにする。](http://www.jgnn.net/ls/2013/08/post-7886.html)
>
> ex2: [普段はIT企業の役員を務める彼**の**、芸人としてのバイト代は……？　エンディングムービーも要チェック。](http://getnews.jp/archives/924827)
>
> ex3:　[※『未来篇』のBD-DVD**の**、劇場での販売の予定はございません。](http://anime-kyokai.com/bd-dvd/)

For ex3, I would have expected something like the next sentence on the page (『過去篇』のBD-DVD**は**、未来篇上映劇場にて引き続き、販売いたします。)

---

I know that the particle の can be used to refer to something aforementioned like in the following example, but it does not seem to be the case in the examples I mentioned.

> A: 誰の教科書ですか。
> B: 私のです。

Comment: I would say they're just usual "possessive" のs, with unusual comma use. Are you saying you suspect they have a different grammatical function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「(Phrase) + の」 always modifies a noun that follows.  That noun can either directly follow 「の」 or after another phrase that directly follows 「の」.

To examine this in your examples:

1. 「そのようなリスクを少しでも減らすための」 modifies 「チェックリスト」.
2. 「普段はIT企業の役員を務める彼の」 modifies 「バイト代」.
3. 「『未来篇』のBD-DVDの」 modifies 「販売」.

Unlike in many other languages including English, the use of commas in Japanese is pretty much left to the discretion of the writer and that often seems to be the cause of confusion and misunderstanding among Japanese-learners.

In your examples, the comma would feel least "needed" in #1 because the noun 「チェックリスト」 follows directly the の-phrase.  The author probably used a comma because the の-phrase is fairly long and s/he saw a need for a "moment of pause" there.

The commas in #2 and #3 seem more "needed" (though still optional) because in each case, there is another shorter の-phrase between the main の-phrase and the noun that it modifies.

Finally, the possesive の that you mentioned at the end has very little to do with the 「の」 that I have discussed above.